# Why return-to-libc shell using system() exits immediately?

Tags: exploit, c, shellcode

I'm experimenting control-flow hijacking attacks on programs written in C on Linux. I'm trying to perform a simple ret-2-libc attack on a program with the No-eXecutable-stack countermeasure enabled. For this purpose I'm returning to `system()` function with argument `/bin/sh`.

But I have a problem: Although my attack works and a shell is spawned successfully, the shell exits immediately after entering the first character! That is, the shell closes after I press any key!

This behavior is also observable in this simple C code:

```
int main() { system("/bin/sh"); return 0; }
```

I compile it using: `gcc code.c -o system`

**Why is this? And how can I fix it?**

I'm experimenting on `Ubuntu-9.04` with `kernel 2.6.28` and `glibc-2.9-1`

---

**Update:** The shell becomes interactive if and only if the first key that I press is <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That is, if the first character that I enter is a `new-line` (`\n`) then the shell remains open and become interactive.

**So can anyone explain what's going on here?**

Comment: Given that you can reproduce the problem with standard and legitimate C code shows this isn't related to your exploit attempts, thus this question is better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndréDaniel True; yet this is not much like a general programming issue and experts in the field of shellcode development can better help. Thus I asked it here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with your code. It this really the only thing you do there? How do you execute it?

Comment: @StenSoft Yes, that's it. I save that code in a file, compile it with the command I mentioned, and run it with `./system`.

Comment: It works on my machine. Can you try another terminal emulator/tty and see if the issue persists?

Answer (score -1):

Okay I believe that system is successfully calling `/bin/sh` but it is calling it with the -c flag.

Try:

```
/bin/bash -c junk
```

That should behave similarly to what you are seeing. You need to play around with the registers to setup the system call so that /bin/sh is called without the -c flag.